# Remote scalable graphics in Apache Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf, apache-flex, svg, actionscript

I have a basic Flex application that shows remote images using `s:Image` tags. According to [the documentation](https://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/Image.html), `s:Image` is constrained to PNG, GIF and JPG filetypes. I would like to include a scalable graphics format (SVG or PDF; the graphics are generated by Python/cairo) instead. I see that I can [embed SVGs](https://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html) within the Flex application at compile-time, but the image content is generated in real-time and must be remote.

Does Flex have a mechanism for inclusion of remote SVG or PDF graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can only embed a SVG but you can't load it into an Image component at runtime. But you can try these libraries that load SVG files and convert them into AS3 display objects. I haven't tried them but they seem fairly easy to use:
https://github.com/LucasLorentz/AS3SVGRenderer
http://www.as3gamegears.com/misc/as3svgrenderer

Alternatively you could just generate bitmap images (JPEGs / PNGs) on the server and load them but naturally it would be better to handle that on the client side to recude the server load

Comment: Thanks. My use case is a little bizarre: I'm using Flex to build live images into a PDF. It works with PNGs, but the scaling is terrible. Client-side isn't an option, but perhaps AS3SVGRenderer is.